# Установка wkhtmltopdf на Windows

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

У меня Windows 8.1 x64, есть готовый проект с формированием PDF. Не могу поставить wkhtmltopdf. Скачал → установил в `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf`. Нужно было установить в папку с расширениями и прописать в `php.ini`?

Comment: Что значит не можете поставить? Установили на диск Ц к примеру, ну и в *php* вызывайте екзешник с параметрами какие вам там нужно, он будет вам генерировать пдфку.

Comment: Решили проблему? мне помогло [**ручное добавление**](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml) в переменную PATH [**пути к папке с wkhtmltopdf**](http://i.imgur.com/KJPE2D4.png). Спасибо.